# Get language string from language code

Tags: foundation

I lookup a book by ISBN from Google Books. I then do this:

`NSString *languageCode = bookInfo[@"language"];`

The `languageCode` is for instance "EN" or "SE".

I want to transform "EN" to "English" and "SE" to "Swedish", in the current locale. (So if the current locale is Swedish, it should instead be "engelska" and "svenska").

Can I do this with Apples `Foundation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**ObjC**

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"it"]; => @"Italian"
```

**Swift**

```
var locale : NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "it") => Italian
```